# Flower, No such file or directory: '/multiproc_dir/gauge_all_8054.db'

Tags: docker, celery, prometheus, python-3.10, flower

I am trying to run flower in docker container using the command

```
celery -A <my_task_folder> flower
```

and I get the following error:

> [E 230619 06:35:06 ioloop:758] Exception in callback
> functools.partial(<bound method EventsState.event of <State: events=4
> tasks=0>>, {'hostname': 'celery@2667b382dde2', 'utcoffset': 0, 'pid':
> 6802, 'clock': 185, 'freq': 2.0, 'active': 4, 'processed': 2722,
> 'loadavg': [1.28, 0.74, 0.41], 'sw_ident': 'py-celery', 'sw_ver':
> '5.2.7', 'sw_sys': 'Linux', 'timestamp': 1687156506.5616019, 'type':
> 'worker-heartbeat', 'local_received': 1687156506.5646658})
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738,
> in _run_callback
> ret = callback()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flower/events.py", line 91, in event
> self.metrics.worker_online.labels(worker_name).set(1)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py",
> line 190, in labels
> self._metrics[labelvalues] = self.**class**(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py",
> line 365, in **init**
> super().**init**(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py",
> line 138, in **init**
> self._metric_init()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py",
> line 378, in _metric_init
> self._value = values.ValueClass(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/values.py",
> line 68, in **init**
> self.__reset()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/values.py",
> line 82, in __reset
> files[file_prefix] = MmapedDict(filename)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/mmap_dict.py",
> line 62, in **init**
> self._f = open(filename, 'rb' if read_mode else 'a+b')
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/multiproc_dir/gauge_all_8054.db'

The versions of the relevant packages are as follows:

```
redis = "4.3.1"
celery = "5.2.7"
flower = "1.0.0"
prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator = "5.8.2"
prometheus-client = "0.17.0"
```

and dockerfile for creating the image is given by:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app/

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry python - --version 1.4.2 && cd /usr/local/bin && ln -s /opt/poetry/bin/poetry && poetry config virtualenvs.create false

# Copy poetry.lock* in case it doesn't exist in the repo
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* /app/

# Allow installing dev dependencies to run tests
ARG INSTALL_DEV=false
RUN bash -c "if [ $INSTALL_DEV == 'true' ] ; then poetry install --no-root ; else poetry install --no-root --no-dev ; fi"

ENV prometheus_multiproc_dir=/multiproc_dir

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers", "4", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "src.main:app"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Flower/Celery, but rather prometheus. As the error message is saying, `/multiproc_dir` does not exist. Simply creating the folder in your `Dockerfile` should solve the problem:

```
ENV prometheus_multiproc_dir=/multiproc_dir
RUN mkdir -p $prometheus_multiproc_dir
```